# Add method call at the end of all main functions in the project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

We have a fairly big Java Project with a lot of main functions in various classes. This is a legacy code that has been inherited, which we are slowly moving over piece by piece to Spring framework. Due to the transition, we have half the objects created with `new` and the other half created as Beans.

Suffice it to say, this causes a lot of headache and results in a situation where context gets initialized twice and in the process we lose reference to one of them. So, main methods invoked from command-line do not exit due to the contexts being alive. As a short-term solution, we are planning to add System.exit calls at the end of all main methods. I know this is a really bad approach, but until the code is in the transition phase and the issue of double contexts gets resolved, we are just looking for a temporary fix.

Which brings me back to my original question. There a lot of main methods in the code-base and adding the System.exit() call manually is not an option. Does IntelliJ have a system by which I can just automatically add the System.exit() calls to the end of all main methods?

Comment: _"with a lot of main functions in various classes"_ -- Java programs have only one `main()` method.  What do you mean?  Do you have a lot of separate Java executables?  Your question is unclear and sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: This is a big project, with a lot of standalone executables. Also, frankly the code is not in good shape and most of these main methods can and should be removed. But, this is not planned in the near term. Just looking for a short term fix for now.

Comment: When you say "lots of standalone executables", what do you mean? 100? 10,000? 50?  I find it hard to understand why you cannot load the entire project into an IDE such as Eclipse and fix the double context initializations?  Sure it will be tedious, and it will probably take a couple of person-days, but if I were you I'd just do it. Otherwise, your "temporary fix" will become enshrined and NEVER be fixed, just piling on more technical debt.

Comment: I hear you. And that is exactly what I had been fighting for. But, I don't make the final decisions :/ As of now, have to execute what has been asked